# Drupal Yslow Performance

Tags: views, 7

Hello  I am using drupal 7  and yslow tool in ff.

it shows me grade B

**Grade F on Make fewer HTTP requests**

This page has 11 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
This page has 5 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.

**As i am not able to combine all javascript and  css files.**

I also enabled cache . but i don't know how it work.

**Grade F on Add Expires headers**

There are 75 static components without a far-future expiration date.

i also made changes in .htacess file still not working .. Please let me know

Grade C on Put JavaScript at bottom

i am using iframe in my website . How to include javascript at bottom for this?

Anybody have idea please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for **Grade F on Make fewer HTTP requests**

Locate them at `admin > configuration > development > performance`. There you'll see two options:

Aggregate and compress css files.
Aggregate Javascript files

[image]

Comment: these are already enabled

Comment: @HituBansal Note that aggregation of JS & CSS files will work when files are added using `drupal_add_js` if you have directly added it like `<script src=''>` then it wont get compressed.